# Cassandra data type duration failed in sstableloader

Tags: cassandra

I have a Cassandra table with the data type "duration".  However, when I tried to use to sstableloader to restore the snapshot into another cluster with the duration data type, I'm getting cannot resolve user type.

The duration data type is a native type within Cassandra.  I'm running Cassandra 3.11.3 community edition.

```
ERROR 17:38:10,726 Error parsing schema for table datakeyspace.retrylog: Cluster.getMetadata().getKeyspace("datakeyspace").getTable("retrylog") will be missing or incomplete
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.UnresolvedUserTypeException: Cannot resolve user type datakeyspace.duration
        at com.datastax.driver.core.DataTypeCqlNameParser.parse(DataTypeCqlNameParser.java:147) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.0.1-shaded.jar:na]
        at com.datastax.driver.core.TableMetadata.build(TableMetadata.java:188) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.0.1-shaded.jar:na]
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SchemaParser.buildTables(SchemaParser.java:176) [cassandra-driver-core-3.0.1-shaded.jar:na]
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SchemaParser.buildKeyspaces(SchemaParser.java:128) [cassandra-driver-core-3.0.1-shaded.jar:na]
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SchemaParser.refresh(SchemaParser.java:64) [cassandra-driver-core-3.0.1-shaded.jar:na]
        at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.refreshSchema(ControlConnection.java:343) [cassandra-driver-core-3.0.1-shaded.jar:na]
        at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.tryConnect(ControlConnection.java:273) [cassandra-driver-core-3.0.1-shaded.jar:na]
        at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:201) [cassandra-driver-core-3.0.1-shaded.jar:na]
        at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:79) [cassandra-driver-core-3.0.1-shaded.jar:na]
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1424) [cassandra-driver-core-3.0.1-shaded.jar:na]
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:163) [cassandra-driver-core-3.0.1-shaded.jar:na]
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:334) [cassandra-driver-core-3.0.1-shaded.jar:na]
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:309) [cassandra-driver-core-3.0.1-shaded.jar:na]
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:251) [cassandra-driver-core-3.0.1-shaded.jar:na]
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.NativeSSTableLoaderClient.init(NativeSSTableLoaderClient.java:73) [apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
```

Comment: Did you find the solution for above?

Comment: I did not find the solution for it.